# How to include a ZIP file from github to an existing android studio project?

Tags: android, import, android-library

It could be weird but I never succeed to import any zip file as a module/library to my project using android studio. I followed many tutorials like this one:https://chmcguir.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/android-studio-importing-library-projects/

But I always have errors.

So someone can explain me how to import a library, as a zip file downloaded on github ( like this one:https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh ) on an android studio project to use it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add error you are getting?

Comment: it depends on the library. But what I'm asking for the proper way to add a library to a project from a zip file downloaded on github.

Comment: Given link has proper way to import any module..!!

Answer (score 0):

The ZIP from Github is nothing but a project. You should look into [adding a project as a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio).

Comment: But like on the step 4, do you paste the full content of the zip file?

Comment: First, you unzip the ZIP file to a local folder. Second, you add a library, and point to the folder where you unpacked the ZIP file.