# how to import library to android project?

Tags: java, android, github, ffmpeg

I want to import this library to my android project but I don't know how.

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java

Comment: In eclipse or studio?

Comment: its a eclipse build , which i can directly import into eclipse OR import in android studo which will build the android dependancies auto.

Comment: how should I import it directly?

Comment: actually it doesn't have any .jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project isn't Gradle library and the simplest way to use it in Android Studio - just export `jar` via Eclipse:

[image]

[image]

Here is result:
 [image]

Hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps :

1. goto File>Project Structure (ctrl+alt+shift+s)
2. click on top green + button.
   [image]
3. Import Eclipse edt project > next > find lib from desktop > next > finish. 
   [image]
   [image]
4. Click on app in project structure and go to dependencies 
   [image]
5. click on + button and select module dependencies  and select your lib 
   project.
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: I used this method and added module but I just want to use it as a library using it in module format wants to set my setting like icon and it makes my app crash, so what should I do ?

Comment: it seems that two program run: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:122)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
            at com.example.sajad.second.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:199)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)

Comment: Have you added AppCompat Lib in your project? in app gradle "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1' "

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering as well.

I got an answer which sadly didnt solve my case, but it will probably help you:
[How to include a ZIP file from github to an existing android studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094933/how-to-include-a-zip-file-from-github-to-an-existing-android-studio-project)

Answer (score 0):

Download this lib, unpack and select after that:
File >> New >> New module

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Click to, build.gradle. After that, dependencies {//add a library}. And finally Sync now.

Comment: I didn't see the link, sorry.